# Capture event on ng-content in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-ngcontent

I am going through [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content) to comprehend angular 2's `ng-content`. I want to capture event which is triggered on `ng-content`. I have following component:

```ts
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'card',
    template: `
    <ng-content (click)="onClick($event)"></ng-content>
    `
})
export class CardComponent {

    onClick(){
        console.log('clicked');
    }
}
```

Here, as you can see I am setting a listener to the `click` event. But for some reasons it is not triggering. It seems like the entire `ng-content` tag is replaced. So to capture the event currently I am doing this:

```ts
template: `
    <div (click)="onClick($event)">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
    `
```

Is there any better way to do this? cause I don't want to wrap my `ng-content` into a `div` to avoid styling issues. Thanks. [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/J0JROxAzVVUf57EhX4aX?p=preview)

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve pretty the same result by binding event listeners to the component element with host declaration.

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'card',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class ButtonComponent {

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(target) {
    console.log('Clicked on: ', target);
  }

}
```

Comment: Accessibility is a problem for this approach. The component `<card>` does not track keyboard users. You'd need a `<button card>` directive which may or not work on your use case. Buttons and anchors `(click)` does properly track keyboard enter or screen reader's "click".

Answer (score 5):

You can use @ContentChild to capture the events of projected component.

Child:

```
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'card-child',
template: `
<div>Card Child component</div>
`
})
export class CardChildComponent {
     @Output customEvent:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter()
}
```

Parent:

```
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'card',
template: `
<ng-content></ng-content>
`
})
export class CardComponent {
    @ContentChild(CardChildComponent) childComp: CardChildComponent;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.childComp.addEventListener("click", ()=>{console.log("clicked"});
        //Below is handling of custom event
        this.childComp.customEvent.subscribe(()=>{console.log("clicked"});
    }
}
```

Below is how the component will be injected.

```
<card>
<card-child></card-child>
</card>
```

Comment: not working if you have multiple card-child components inside card component. works only for first one

Answer (score 0):

`<ng-content>` is just a placeholder to transclude the contents inside a component's tags. Angular replaces it.

The only option to avoid using the `DIV` solution, would be to create your own version of `ng-content`.

Basically, you just create an empty component and, in the template, you only put a `<ng-content>` tag. If you call that component `AppContentComponent` (app-content), then you can, in your components,

```
<app-content (click)="onClick()">
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</app-content>
```

Of course, this is a bit convoluted, and you end up wrapping your transcluded content into another tag (not a `<div>`, but an `<app-content>`), though, of course, initially you didn't mind the content being wrapped by an `<ng-content>` so I suppose it might work for you.